# xtabond2: instrument matrix depends on dataset in memory

Tags: stata

The following two `xtabond2` estimation commands give the same estimation results:

```
webuse abdata, clear
gen wL3=l3.w
gen wL2=l2.w
xtabond2 n nL1 w yr* if wL3~=., gmm(w, lag(1 1)) iv(yr*) nolevel robust 
keep if wL2~=. 
xtabond2 n nL1 w yr*, gmm(w, lag(1 1)) iv(yr*) nolevel robust
```

whereas the following two `xtabond2` estimation commands give different estimation results (even though they are based on the same samples and specify their instrument sets equivalently):

```
webuse abdata, clear
gen wL3=l3.w
gen wL2=l2.w
xtabond2 n nL1 w yr* if wL3~=., gmm(w, lag(1 2)) iv(yr*) nolevel robust 
keep if wL2~=. 
xtabond2 n nL1 w yr*, gmm(w, lag(1 2)) iv(yr*) nolevel robust
```

In the latter example, xtabond2 reports 18 instruments in the first estimation and 17 instruments in the second estimation.

[From inspecting the instrument matrices, it appears that `xtabond2` constructs the instrument matrix from all the data in memory, disregarding the pre-estimation sample restrictions on the dependent and independent variables imposed by the `if` statement (i.e. `xtabond2` ignores the `if wL3~=.`).]

**My question is**: is there a way to produce the estimation results from

```
keep if wL2~=. 
xtabond2 n nL1 w yr*, gmm(w, lag(1 2)) iv(yr*) nolevel robust
```

above without first dropping observations? Is there a clever way to control the number of lags of the data in memory to use as instruments that would achieve the same result without dropping observations?

It seems inefficient to have to subset a master dataset N times to apply `xtabond2` to N different subsets of the data (while also restricting the sample from which the instrument sets are constructed).

Comment: It's hard to see this as a programming problem of yours. You are having trouble interpreting results from `xtabond2`. I'd advise posting this on Statalist or contacting the program author. I would like to be wrong, but this seems too recondite (and too statistical) to have a good chance of an answer here.

Comment: I have no problem interpreting output from `xtabond2`. I'm asking if there is a better set of commands in Stata [i.e. a programmatic question] to produce the output from the minimal working example. This doesn't strictly speaking require knowledge of statistics. I have been through Roodman's (2009) paper and the `xtabond2` help files in detail and they don't seem to address this issue. Good advice to contact the author, thanks.

Comment: My work-around at the moment is 'hacky': I save a temporary dataset at the beginning of my script, and then wrap each call to `xtabond2` in `drop if ...` and `use ..., clear` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping observations seems to be the only way (at the moment) to control/restrict the observations that enter the instrument matrix.

Stata has built-in functionality for dropping observations and then restoring the original dataset. Rather than doing

```
drop if ... 
xtabond2 ...
use ..., clear
```

one could instead do

```
preserve
xtabond2 ...
restore
```

See `help preserve` for more information.

Note that recovering `e(sample)` after this procedure will be difficult, because `restore` will kill it. The only suggestion I have found is given by Richard Williams [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-06/msg00609.html)

```
> I suppose if you really wanted/needed to keep e(sample) alive, you 
> could create and save a new dataset before you did you restore, and 
> then merge your original data set with the one that contained 
> e(sample).    Alternatively, I suppose it wouldn't be too hard to 
> figure out the commands that would generate e(sample) if you didn't 
> already have it.
```